# How to reduce vertical space before and after Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am using `scrreprt` and `biblatex` at the moment to generate my bibliography. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}

\begin{filecontents}{myrefs.bib}
@Book{Knuth:1990,
    author    = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    title     = {The {\TeX}book},
    year      = {1990},
    isbn      = {0-201-13447-0},
    publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
}

@Book{Lamport:94,
    author    = {Lamport, Leslie},
    title     = {\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System},
    year      = {1994},
    isbn      = {0-021-52983-1},
    publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{myrefs.bib}

\begin{document}

% here is the text with some references...

% now we create the bibliography
\begingroup
    \begin{onehalfspacing}
        \printbibliography
    \end{onehalfspacing}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

This works nicely, but there is a lot of white space created before and also after the header "Bibliography" in my document. I am kind of constrained with space, and I would like to fit all references on one page.
Is there any way to adjust the vertical space before and after the header precisely to certain values? For example 12pt?
Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Please make your example into a proper example others can copy and test.

Comment: how can I do this? I cannot post multiple tex files here

Comment: Yes you can paste it into your question. But you do not need many files. Make it as minimal as possible